# How to print dot(".") separated acronyms from a given string

Tags: python, list, acronym

help me with this solution:
I have to print dot-separated acronyms. For example "Very Important Person"= V.I.P
The code that I wrote is as follows:

```
string=input()
str_list=string.split()
acronym=""
for word in str_list:
    acronym+= word[0]+"."
print(acronym.upper())
```

The expected output is for "Very Important Person"= V.I.P, but I am getting V.I.P.
So how can I stop python after it puts two dots?
Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

You could do it like this:

```
s = "Very Important Person"
print('.'.join(c[0] for c in s.split()))
```

**Output:**

```
V.I.P
```

Answer (score 0):

The code that you wrote adds a dot after each letter of the acronym. You can simply remove the last dot using string slicing.

```py
string=input()
str_list=string.split()
acronym=""
for word in str_list:
    acronym+= word[0]+"."
# remove last character
acronym=acronym[:-1]
print(acronym.upper())
```